# FitNesse/Waferslim Tabletable with multiple rows

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, fitnesse

I'm using [Waferslim](https://launchpad.net/waferslim) to tie in to Fitnesse with Python. I've gotten the interaction working properly, however, I'm having problems implementing the Tabletable type in FitNesse. The [Waferslim example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~prime8/waferslim/main/view/head:/src/waferslim/examples/table_table.py) given only has one row in the table, but I'm trying to get this to work with multiple rows.

It seems that the expected return for a single row table is something like this:

```
[['no change', 'no change',...], ['pass', 'pass',...]]
```

Now, one would expect that by doing something like:

```
[
[['no change', 'no change',...], ['pass', 'pass',...]],
[['no change', 'no change',...], ['pass', 'pass',...]],
]
```

After all that my question is, has anyone successfully managed to get a Tabletable with multiple rows to work with FitNesse and Waferslim? Or do I just have to use a bunch of single row tables to test a large data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'no change' list corresponds to the first column of the table, and the 'pass/fail/whatever' goes to the second row.

For the longest time I'd thought that both lists were needed on each row, which was the root of the problem. So, to return values on multiple rows you would send back a list that looks like this:

```
[
['no change', 'no change', 'no change'], #This is the 'table header' row
['pass', 'pass', 'pass'], #This is the first row that is actually tested
['pass', 'pass', 'pass'] #This is the second row that is tested
]
```

When you look at it that way, it's blindingly obvious.